# Any reason the Pages Modules would not keep my assigned uri?

Tags: module, url, pages

It will not keep the uri that I type into the field in my entry. When I go back into the entry, it is back to the example/pages/uri. I have used module on this site in the past, I had uninstalled it and now re-installed it. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Which version of EE are you running?

Comment: oh, sorry, 2.5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth ensuring that the Pages module is properly installed (Addons > Modules | Status: Installed). Also, it's worth trying Addons > Modules > Run Module Updates in top right corner of the page.

Other than that ensure that the Pages module is configured correctly in Pages > Module Configuration. Ensure that you've set the default blog and template to use.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question Ian, yes installed. I didn't realize that the "updates" button was over there, so I ran that. I have set the configuration defaults also, but to no avail, the uri field is still not sticking. oh, I also tried logging out between un-install and re-install again, just-in-case there was a  server issue last time I tried. More ideas welcome...

Comment: The pages_uri field is on the PUBLISH TAB, this is the field that was **not** staying assigned. What I didn't notice, was the pages_uri field was also on the PAGES TAB of my entry. When I populated the field in the PAGES TAB it auto-populated the field on the PUBLISH TAB. Thus, my problem is solved -- it now stays assigned.

Comment: Ah, that will be why. Yes, when publishing an entry as a *Page* always make sure you use the *Pages* tab to set the URI. To save confusion you may want to hide the  *URL Title* field from the *Publish* tab. (Toggle 'show toolbar' on the right, hide the URL Title field, and Save Layout.